# Change UIViewCotroller custom class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I accidentally assigned the same custom class to two UIViewControllers in Storyboard:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
```

With this the app ran properly. But when I change the custom class for the second View Controller from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` the app crashes when the second View Controller loads. How do I rectify this situation?

Comment: Well... what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Oh, you need put more detail.

Answer (score 0):

More information is definitely needed here. However, one of the things to look for is that if you are using the `FirstViewController` class in code somewhere (in `-prepareForSegue` for the presenting UIViewController for instance), you'll need to make sure to change that code so that it's using the proper pointer for the class when referencing the SecondViewController class.

For instance, if you do the following and the destinationViewController is of class `SecondViewController`, then you will get a crash:

`FirstViewController *firstView = (FirstViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];`

If you could post the presenting class and the `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` classes, then we can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassingly obvious now, but I found the problem arose from a button being linked to an IBAction in the the FirstViewController class. When the app was run it crashed because of the improper link.